Need help with understanding conditional probability distributions with multiple random variables
I'm trying to understand the following steps that were presented in some lecture notes on machine learning that I was reading. In this settting we want to approximate a function $f^*: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ with a function from a parameterized function class $\mathcal{F}(\Theta)$ where each function in said class depends on some parameters $\theta \in \Theta$. We are given the inputs $x_{1:n}$ and the labels $y_{1:n}$, where we use the notation $x_{1:n} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)^T$.  We assume that the labels are i.i.d and that $y_i \sim p( \cdot | x_i, \theta)$ holds. Furthermore, we assume that the parameter $\theta$ has a prior distribution $p(\theta)$. We now wish to predict the output $y^*$ at a new input $x^*$ by conditioning on $\theta$:
$$p(y^* | x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = \int_{\Theta}p(y^*, \theta | x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) d\theta = \int_{\Theta}p(y^* | x^*, \theta) \cdot p(\theta | x_{1:n}, y_{1:n})d\theta,$$
According to the lecture notes, the first equality follows from the sum rule, which is stated as
$$p(x_{1:i - 1}, x_{i + 1:n}) = \int_{X_i(\Omega)}p(x_{1:i-1},x_i, x_{i + 1: n}) dx_i,$$
and the second equality follows from $y^* \perp x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} | \theta$ and the product rule, which is stated as
$$p(x_{1:n}) = p(x_1) \prod_{i = 2}^np(x_i | x_{1: i-1}).$$
The first equality I believe I understand, since by definition of the conditional probability distribution we have
$$p(x_{1:i-1}, x_{i+1:n} | y_{1:n}) = \frac{p(x_{1:i-1}, x_{i+1:n}, y_{1:n})}{p(y_{1:n})} = \frac{\int_{X_i(\Omega)}p(x_{1:i-1},x_i, x_{i + 1: n}, y_{1:n}) dx_i}{p(y_{1:n})} = $$
$$ = \frac{\int_{X_i(\Omega)} p(y_{1:n})p(x_{1:i-1},x_i, x_{i + 1: n} | y_{1:n}) dx_i}{p(y_{1:n})}  = \int_{X_i(\Omega)}p(x_{1:i-1},x_i, x_{i + 1: n} | y_{1:n}) dx_i.$$
However, I don't understand how the second equality follows from $y^* \perp x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} | \theta$ and the stated product rule.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

In general it doesn't, if $x^*$ (for which we here in CV know nothing about) is/is treated as a random variable, and not as a constant.
The general expression would be
$$p(y^*, \theta | x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = p(y^* | \theta, x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n})\cdot p( \theta | x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}).$$
1. The notes invoke
$$y^* \perp x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} | \theta$$
to write
$$p(y^* | \theta, x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = p(y^* | \theta, x^*).$$
This is not in general correct, because of the presence of $x^*$ (if it is a random variable and not a constant).
What is true, is that given $y^* \perp x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} | \theta$, we have
$$p(y^* | \theta, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = p(y^* | \theta).$$
This is indeed one of the ways to express conditional independence: if $y^*$ is independent from $(x_{1:n}, y_{1:n})$ given $\theta$, then conditioning the distribution of $y^*$ on $(x_{1:n}, y_{1:n})$ when we have already conditioned it on $\theta$, does not change a thing, so we can eliminate $(x_{1:n}, y_{1:n})$ from the conditioning arguments.
But the presence of $x^*$, if it is a random variable, may not allow this property to pass through; it may be the case that, even though
$$y^* \perp x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} | \theta$$
it also holds that
$$y^* {\rm not\; independent}\; \{x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} \}| \theta.$$
2. Also it appears the notes imply that
$$\theta \perp x^* | x_{1:n}, y_{1:n} $$
and so they equate
$$p( \theta | x^*, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = p( \theta | x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}).$$
Again, we know nothing about $x^*$. If the OP does, they may figure this out.

Thank you for your response! I tried to clarify what the variables mean in my question. It would seem to me that $x^*$ is considered a constant in this setting. However, I don't understand why one would condition on a constant, since as I understand it, we can simply ignore them when it comes to conditional distributions. Also, could you provide an explanation for the general expression that you provided at the start, I can't seem to derive it myself.

@Dude3400 It is just the chain rule, $p(x,y) = p(x|y)p(y)$, only, with additional conditioning variables that are part of the environment. And you are right in your comments about $x^$, but you didn't give any information on it in your post. Didn't the notes clarify what $x^$ is? Sometimes we treat things as constant in one setting, while in another they may be random variables, and we include them in notation for completeness.

The only information that is provided for $x^$ is that it is a new input for which we wish to predict the output $y^$. Therefore, I believe it is assumed that $x^*$ is a fixed value and thus a constant. As to the general expression in your post, I believe that I understand how the chain rule is applied intuitively, but I can't seem to justify it mathematically. For three random variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ we have $$p(x,y|z) = \frac{p(z)p(x|z)p(y|x,z)}{p(z)} = p(x|z)p(y|x,z),$$ and at this point I'm stuck.

So since $x^*$ is a "new input", maybe it is considered statistically independent of everything else, and then the result of the notes passes through. On the other issue, you already arrived at what I wrote.

But in order to get what you wrote, wouldn't I have to get $p(x, y | z) = p(x | y, z) \cdot p(y | x, z)$? In my case, when I cancel out $p(z)$, I get $p(x, y | z) = p(x | z)p(y | x, z)$.

@Dude3400 No. Look at my expression again. It is exactly what you found. $y^$ is $y$, $\theta$ is $x$, and  $(x^, x_{1:n}, y_{1:n})$ are $z$.

You are in fact right, sorry for the misunderstanding and thank you for your answer and patience. I believe that's my cue to get some shut-eye.
